# JQuery myArray[myVarriable] is undefined, even though i've defined it

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, undefined

Ok, let me show you what im trying to make here,
There are 4 objects, similar to this one:

```
var links = {name: "Links", id: "links", index: 0};
```

I place them inside an array:

```
var pages = [links,about,projects,contact];
```

I created this function:

```
function active_page(selected){
  var active = 0;
  $("[id="+pages[selected].id+"]").show();
}
```

Then i run active_page(0) in

```
$(function(){
  active_page(active);
});
```

And im getting this error:

```
pages[selected] is undefined
```

The whole .js file is here:
http://pastebin.com/2rBWiVJF

The error im getting is in line 26

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem.  The actual issue lies in your `clicked()` function.

The `for` loop doesn't create a new scope, so you're always referring to the same `i` variable, which will hold the latest value after the loop.

```
function clicked() {
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        $("[id=" + pages[i].id + "_btn]").mousedown(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 1) {
                // the "i" passed is always going to be the same as "pages.length"
                active_page(i);
                active = i;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The only way to scope a variable in JavaScript is in a function. So you should pass `i` to a new function invocation in order to scope it.

```
function clicked() {
    // used to scope the value of "i", and return a function
    //     that references it.
    function createHandler(this_i) {
        return function (e) {
            if (e.which == 1) {
                active_page(this_i);
                active = this_i;
            }
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        $("[id=" + pages[i].id + "_btn]").mousedown(createHandler(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var active = 0;
var pages  = [{name: "Links", id: "links"}, 
          {name: "About", id: "about"}, 
          {name: "Projects", id: "projects"}, 
          {name: "Contact", id: "contact"];

function active_page(selected){
   $('#' + pages[selected].id).show();
}

$(function(){
  active_page(active);
});
```